# Can SPARQL's 'from' / 'from named' clauses be used to refer to remote files?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ttl, turtle-rdf

I know that SPARQL's 'from' and 'from named' clauses can be used to specify RDF datasets, and I have had luck using them within triplestore repositories to refer to named graphs that are loaded into those repositories. However, an example in section 13.2.3 of the [SPARQL 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#specDataset) seems to indicate that you can specify remote files to query against using 'from' or 'from named'. Sure enough, I have had luck doing this with [ARQ](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/). You can use 'from named' and point to an RDF file hosted on the web and query against it using this tool. However, I don't seem to get this functionality when using triplestores. Is this to be expected? Has anyone else used 'from' / 'from named' for something like this?

Comment: Yes - FROM and FROM NAMED pick documents for graphs out of some sets of graphs. That set may be "the web" or the named graphs of a dataset. Apache Jena will behave like other triple stores when FROM/FROM NAMED is used with a TDB dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most RDF DBMS ("triple-stores") and SPARQL processors do not use the URL(s) you put in the `FROM` or `FROM NAMED` clause(s) to retrieve (a) file(s) from the Web and read its/their contents. Instead, you usually have a database into which you previously loaded some RDF data, and the `FROM [NAMED]` clause in your query is used to identify a subset of that data (commonly referred to as a "named graph").

That said, [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (from my employer, [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/)) has a few ways to retrieve/dereference and load (either persistently or transiently) on the fly. For instance, see [Enhancements the Virtuoso Sponger brings to SPARQL](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSpongerLinkedDataHooksIntoSPARQL).

Other SPARQL processors and/or triple-stores may provide similar functionality, usually by implementation-specific means, but this is not currently part of [standard SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-overview/), your interpretation of [§13.2.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#specDataset) notwithstanding.